# Validate windows user before logged in MVC application

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

My requirement is to get the username of windows system user and validate that username with the application database. If the user exists in the table I have to navigate him to the homepage of the application. I have tried below code but User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is always false. How can I set User.Identity.IsAuthenticated for the windows user?

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : BaseController
{

    private ViewboxUserManager UserManager { get { return Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ViewboxUserManager>(); } }


    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        var adUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString();
        string windowsUser = (adUser.IndexOf(@"\") >= 0) ? adUser.Substring(adUser.IndexOf(@"\") + 1) : adUser;

        var user = UserManager.FindByNameAsync(windowsUser);

        if (user != null)
        {
            bool isLoginPage = false;
            if (Request.Cookies["IsLogin"] != null) isLoginPage = true;
            if (isLoginPage && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "" });
            }
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        ViewBag.Title = "Login";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need to read `BaseController.User`. Don't call `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`. And why do you need to allow anonymous?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it like this:

```
var userIdentity = await CreateUserIdentityAsync(user).WithCurrentCulture();
                AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
                AuthenticationManager.SignIn(userIdentity);
```